# How to fix loading a PDF file from Resources?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using c# and visual studio 2017. I have a web browser view in my windows form application. I'm trying to view a PDF file in the web browser view but can't get it to load from my resources folder. I do not want to store the file locally as I want to be able to use it on another PC.

In Resources.resx I have clicked "Add Resource" - "Add existing file" - selected my PDF "test.pdf" and then in properties, I've set the file to "Embedded Resource" and "Copy Always"

I am trying to load the file like this:

```
public void loadPDF()
    {
   string file = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,   @"projectPDF\projectPDF\Resources\test.pdf");           
            this.webView.Navigate(file);           


    }
```

and then call it on a button click event like this: loadPDF();

At the moment, the file isn't displaying in the web browser view when I click the button. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: An embedded resources does not exist as a disk file...and the resources directory is a Visual Studio only thing - they dont exist at runtime

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp I’m not sure that I understand. Can you provide an answer to show me how I would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedded resources are not stored in a magic "Folder" its is literally embedded into the EXE itself and therefor cannot be changed after your program builds.

The file that is copied into your solution is merely a copy of the file you selected to embed, while building the assembly it uses this copy to embed because the original one might no longer be at the path you specified earlier, especially when working in teams on different computers.

The "Copy Always" flag has no meaning for the embedded resources, this is just to indicate to Visual Studio that the file should be copied to the "bin/Debug" folder when the program builds (using "Debug" configuration).

You can do something along these lines to store the PDF in a temporary file and then show it:

```
var pdfBytes = Properties.Resources.MY_PDF; // Where "MY_PDF" is the name of your resource
var fileTempPath = Path.GetTempFileName(); // Get a temp file path
File.WriteAllBytes(fileTempPath, pdfBytes); // Write the temp file with PDF contents
webView.Navigate(fileTempPath); // navigate to the temp file
```

dont forget to cleanup your temp files when youre done with the pdf!

Comment: This Solution Works Perfectly. tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without temp file:

```
    public static async void test(byte[] pdfBytes)
    {

        string pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes);

        string html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head>"
                       + "<style>"
                       + "body { margin: 0; }"
                       + "iframe {display: block; background: #000; border: none; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;}"
                       + "</style>"
                       + $"<body> " + $" <iframe src = \"data: Application/pdf; base64,{pdfBase64} \" > " + " </iframe></body></html> ";


        var webView = new WebView2();

        var win = new System.Windows.Window();

        win.Content = webView;
        win.Loaded += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
            webView.NavigateToString(html);
        };

        win.Show();
    }
```

It opens a new wpf window to show the .pdf file.

Usage:

```
test(Properties.Resources.MY_PDF)
```

Edit:
According to the documentation:

> The htmlContent parameter may not be larger than 2 MB (2 * 1024 * 1024
> bytes)

Comment: It just shows the pdf in a new window, no download required.
I'm using it with a 800kb pdf file (8 pages including images).

Edit: The doc about NavigateToString says: "The htmlContent parameter may not be larger than 2 MB (2 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)"